# How to improve redundancy in HTML and ROR with partials?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, redundancy

I have these 2 partials written for my Ruby on Rails application. Is there any clever way two merge them into one?  Copy pasting one partial into the other is not allowed

What I would like to have is something like this:

@member = 'Player'
render 'team/team_partial'

@member = 'Staff'
render 'team/team_partial'

Or any other clever way that deals with the redundancy of the code is accepted.

1. ```html
   .row  
     .col-md-6.info_block    
           .row  
             .col-md-10.col-md-offset-1  
               = icon 'user'  
               .caption  
                 h3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3   
                   |Players:  
                 table  
                   tbody  
                     - @team.players.each do |player|  
                       tr  
                         td = icon 'check'  
                         td   
                           |Name:   
                           a href= '#'  
                             = player.name  
                         td   
                           = form_for(@team, url: team_path(@team), method: :delete, html:{class:"team_member_form"}) do |f|  
                             = hidden_field_tag :player, player.id  
                             = f.submit "Delete", class:"btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  
                 button type="button" class="btn btn-success showModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-member="Player"  
                   |Add Player
   ```
  2.

```html
.row
          .col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
            = icon 'user'
            .caption
              h3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3 
                |Staff:
              table
                tbody
                  - @team.staff.each do |staff|
                    tr
                      td = icon 'check'
                      td 
                        |Name: 
                        a href= #
                          = staff.name
                      td 
                        = form_for(@team, url: team_path(@team), method: :delete, html:{class:"team_member_form"}) do |f|
                          = hidden_field_tag :staff, staff.id
                          = f.submit "Delete", class:"btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
              button type="button" class="btn btn-success showModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-member="Staff"
                i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
                |Add Staff
```

Comment: `<%= render "team/team_partial", staff: @member %>`

Comment: Thank you for replying! Sorry if I was a big vague but my question was how can you create the _team_partial.html file by combining the two partials above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the partial this way, member_type define the type of member "staff" or "players"

```
<%= render "team/team_partial", :locals => {:team => @member, :member_type => @member.type} %>
```

In view

```
.row
      .col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
        = icon 'user'
        .caption
          h3.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3 
            |#{member_type}:
          table
            tbody
              - @team.#{member_type}.each do |member|
                tr
                  td = icon 'check'
                  td 
                    |Name: 
                    a href= #
                      = member.name
                  td 
                    = form_for(@team, url: team_path(@team), method: :delete, html:{class:"team_member_form"}) do |f|
                      = hidden_field_tag #{member_type}.to_s, member.id
                      = f.submit "Delete", class:"btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
          button type="button" class="btn btn-success showModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-member= #{member_type}
            i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
            |Add #{member_type}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really am grateful!

Comment: your're welcome, just see in view somewhere you need `player` rather than `players` you can always use `'players'.singularize`

Comment: Hey Sontya! I tried running this line of code but it never works:  @team.#{member_type}.each

Comment: It does not do anything. Do you have any idea on how I may convert a method name from a string> For example if I have the method "members" to convert it so that I may cal team.members?

Comment: I have managed to found the answer! the "send" method achieves exactly what i want

Comment: `@team.instance_variable_set('@'+#{member_type}, new_value)`, try something like this. Thats good about to suggest you that only. Still it not work for you, let me know

Comment: I finally managed to rewrite my code using your help! Thank you!